# Difference between similar looking Python for-loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-2.x, conventions

I was curious about the way this

```
for _ in range(10): #1
```

**loop#1** execution is different from

```
for i in range(10): #2
```

**loop#2**  execution. They certainly do look exactly the same, but, I wanted to have a clear understanding and know if their functioning under the hood is also **exactly** the same?  Also, I know when both these types of loops are used, so, I am **not** looking for an answer to "When to use What?".

I had already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python), but, it doesn't provide a clear distinction and the working of the two under the hood.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the single underscore "\_" variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in python the underscore character it's a valid var name, so bot snippets are the same but with different var names, like @AK47 says, use de under score if you don't want use the var inside the loop, but the `_` it's a valid var name so you can used inside the loop:

[image]

some frameworks like django use the underscore in their code patterns:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They both do the exact same thing

The former is used if the variable is disposable and not usually referenced in the loop

```
for _ in range(10): #1
```

The latter is used if you plan to reference the variable name within the loop

```
for i in range(10): #2
```

It's boils down to the python naming convention -- under the hood, both loops function in the exact same way

Comment: I'd add that `_` is simply unused by convention, Python treats it as a valid usable variable name.